# jQuery for wap2.0 development and convenience of this approach

Tags: jquery, mobile, wap

I need to build a mobile app for a customer that basically manage text data (login, list items, send forms). This app is not for global use but rather for workers inside a company.

1.- So as I want reach the the most devices as possible I choose wap2.0 over customs solutions for android or iphone. (First question: Am I right on this?)

2.- Supposing that I am right and wap2.0 (xhtml mobile profiles) is the best approach. Can I use jQuery for this?

3.- Is really so widely supported this wap2.0 technology in mobiles devices at this time (post 2010)

Thanks.-

Comment: Have you had a look at [jQuery's mobile framework](http://jquerymobile.com/) to see if it will help you?

Comment: Yes, thanks. Indeed I will use it. But my questions is more general. I want to know how good is my decision of use wpa2.0 I have edited my question to reflect this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. WAP 2.0 can be seen as [XHTML MP (Mobile Profile)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XHTML_Mobile_Profile) markup.
   This is a good standard to use because it will work on all new devices, as well as most old devices.
2. jQuery is more of a JavaScript framework, and XHTML-MP doesn't specify any javascript standard.  So the javascript/jquery support for it will have to be looked at on a case to case basis.
3. Yes, it's covered by pretty much all mobile devices with a normal browser, especially 2010+. Because any html browser will have to support this "WAP2.0"/XHTML-MP because it is just a subset.